# Android - Singleton Class only updating on second refresh

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have a singleton class called `DataManager`. I update some data in `DataManager` when I call `onStop()` in a class (`activity`) called `userProfile`. It takes the values from some text input boxes and updates the `User` Object in `DataManger`. I navigate through my app with a `BottomNavigationView` - so when I press the home icon from the `userProfile` view, I should call the `userProfile` `onStop()` and update the values. That works correctly. I stepped through the code and the values in my `singleton` class are updated correctly. The problem occurs when I try to read the values from the home page. The values have not been updated yet. BUT if I reopen the view or open another view, the values in `DataManager` are the correct updated values. What do you think the issue is?

I'm not sure if its relevant, but home and `userProfile` both inherit from a base class which holds the `onCreate()` method from both child classes.

`Singleton` class called `DataManager`:

```
public class DataManager {

private static DataManager only_instance = null;

public List<Facility> facilities;
public List<Procedure> procedures;
public static User theUser;

public DataManager(){
    only_instance.theUser = new User();
}

public static DataManager getInstance(){
    if(only_instance == null){
        only_instance = new DataManager();
    }

    return only_instance;
}
}
```

The onStop() method from userProfile

```
@Override
    protected void onStop(){
super.onStop();    

DataManager dm = DataManager.getInstance();

dm.theUser.<SET LOTS OF VALUES>
}
```

Comment: Are you GOING BACK from userProfile to homePage?

Comment: It is generally good practice to write a private default constructor so you don't accidentally create a new instance without meaning to. Also as @Archit pointed out you should enclose new object creation inside a synchronize block. Or better yet make the entire method synchronized.

Comment: @TentenPonce I don't think I'm going back - It's just to different activities that I toggle back and forth using a Bottom Navigation Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually lies in the android lifecycle. For some reason the onCreate() function was being called in the home page class before the onStop() function was being called in the userProfile class. I'm honestly not exactly why - but changing onStop() to onPause() solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're lazily loading your Singleton. It works when you refresh your app because you're calling onStop and initializing your Singleton. But before then, you have no Singleton instance loaded (it's null). If you remove lazy initialization it will work. Change

```
if(only_instance == null){ //This is called "lazy loading"
    only_instance = new DataManager();
}
```

to

```
private static final DataManager only_instance = new DataManager(); //you can optionally add final here if you're removing lazy loading. In fact, it's probably best practice to do so.

public List<Facility> facilities;
public List<Procedure> procedures;
public static User theUser;

public DataManager(){
    only_instance.theUser = new User();
}

public static DataManager getInstance(){
    return only_instance;
}
```

This way, you're Singleton instance will be loaded as soon as the class is loaded. If you don't need the instance of your Singleton immediately, lazy loading is nice, but in your case you need it right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it may be due to synchronisation problem. so we should use Thread Safe Singleton with help of synchronized() keyword like below:

```
    ASingleton result = instance;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                result = instance;
                if (result == null)
                    instance = result = new ASingleton();
            }
        }
        return result;
```

and If you are not using theUser without DataManager instance then it should not be static.

for more about Thread Safe Singleton
You can refer this link for more info

> https://www.journaldev.com/171/thread-safety-in-java-singleton-classes-with-example-code